# How to change checkbox to Icon in Algolia Instant Search?

Tags: html, css, algolia

Algolia instand search provides checkbox and label as follows:

```
<label class="ais-RefinementList-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" value="Stroke">
    <span class="ais-RefinementList-labelText">Stroke</span> <span class="ais-RefinementList-count">986</span> 
</label>
```

I would love to replace the default checkbox with an Font Awesome Icon.
The only way to do so is based on this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4huzr/

But here the setup is completly different `<input /><label>` instead of `<label><input /></label>`.
Can it be achieved anyway?

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/d73txLpj/
If you can provide a working example of your code <label><input /> then I can help you with adding FontAwesome in there too

Comment: if you can have a working snippet we can help

Comment: I have prepared a sample right here => https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/f5j9d73m/16/
Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add same css for span also:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
 
input[type=checkbox] + label,
input[type=checkbox] + span
{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:before,
input[type=checkbox] + span:before
{
  content:"";
  background: #999;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left:0 ;
  top: 2px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + span:before
{
  content: "\f00c";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
   background: blue;
   color:#fff;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
This one works with a replacement:<br />
<input type='checkbox' name='thing1' value='valuable' id="thing1"/>
<label for="thing1">Thing 1</label>


<hr />

This one does not:<br />
<label class="ais-RefinementList-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" value="Stroke">
    <span class="ais-RefinementList-labelText">Thing 2</span> 
</label>
```